# Iterating through nested objects applying .includes()

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, nested-loops

I have an object like this so for example:

```
const obj = 
{
    '140': {
        name: 'Jim',
        id: 140,
        link: 'http://a-website.com',
        hashKey: 'sdfsdgoihn21oi3hoh',
        customer_id: 13425
    },
    '183': {
        name: 'Foo',
        id: 183,
        link: 'http://a-website.com/abc',
        hashKey: 'xccxvq3z',
        customer_id: 1421
    },
    '143': {
        name: 'Bob',
        id: 143,
        link: 'http://a-website.com/123',
        hashKey: 'xcnbovisd132z',
        customer_id: 13651
    },
    '-40': {
        rgb: {
            b: 42,
            g: 114,
            r: 94
        },
        id: -40,
    },
    '-140': {
        rgb: {
            b: 77,
            g: 17,
            r: 55
        },
        done: true,
        id: -140
    }
}
```

I would like to iterate through the objects and look for any object's name that includes the letter 'o' using `<String>.includes('o');` I tried to use obj.forEach(fn) and iterate through them checking if the name property exists and then check if the obj.name includes o however, I was unable to use forEach as I got the error obj.forEach is not a function.

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Apply your existing code to an array which you can get by `Object.keys(obj)`.

Comment: FYI, you have [**lots** of options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263127/157247).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are not arrays, so you can't use `forEach`. Instead, iterate over the keys/values/entries (whatever you need), check to see if the `.name` property exists on the object and is a string, and if so, use `.includes`:

```js
const obj={'140':{name:'Jim',id:140,link:'http://a-website.com',hashKey:'sdfsdgoihn21oi3hoh',customer_id:13425},'183':{name:'Foo',id:183,link:'http://a-website.com/abc',hashKey:'xccxvq3z',customer_id:1421},'143':{name:'Bob',id:143,link:'http://a-website.com/123',hashKey:'xcnbovisd132z',customer_id:13651},'-40':{rgb:{b:42,g:114,r:94},id:-40,},'-140':{rgb:{b:77,g:17,r:55},done:!0,id:-140}};

console.log(
  Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, { name }]) => (
    typeof name === 'string' && name.includes('o')
  ))
);
```